# How to find the quadratic equation with 2 variables, given 2 functions independent of the other variable.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been asked to find the function for f(a,b).
given that

```
f(a,0) = .02*((a-2)^2) + 170
f(0,b) = 0.00125 * (b^2) + 170.08
```

Can you give me a suggestion of how I would go about finding the equation for f(a,b)? Would I require any more information about this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily find *one* quadratic function $f(x,y)$ that satisfies those conditions, but the problem is that there are infinite such functions and you will not know if it is correct, if you do not know other values.

Let me change the names of the function and of the variables to avoid repetitions. So I'm assuming you are looking for a function $g$ and that you know that $g(x,0)=0.02 (x-2)^2 + 170$ and $g(0,y)=0.00125 y^2 + 170.08$.

In general a quadratic function $g(x,y)$ in two variables $x$ and $y$ has the form
$$
g(x,y) = ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+f
$$
where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are constants.

Here you know that $g(x,0)$ is always equal to $0.02(x-2)^2 + 170=0.02x^2-0.08x +170.08$, and since $g(x,0)=ax^2+dx+f$ this means that $a=0.02$, $d=-0.08$ and $f=170.08$.

Let's do the same for the other variable. We have that $g(0,y)=by^2+ey+f$ must be equal to  $0.00125 y^2 + 170.08$. This means that $b=0.00125$, $e=0$ and $f=170.08$.

OK. The nice fact is that the value of the constant $f$ that we deduce from the first and second case is the same $f=170.08$.

The bad fact is that we cannot say anything at all about the term $cxy$. We have no information. In practice, we can write
$$
g(x,y) = 0.02x^2 + 0.00125 y^2 -0.08x + 170.08 + c x y
$$
and whatever value we choose for the constant $c$, this function $g(x,y)$ will satisfy the initial constraints.

In practice we cannot really reconstruct the "true" $g(x,y)$ without further information.

Even a single value $g(x,y)=k$ with $x,y\neq 0$ is sufficient to determine $c$.